# How can I convert response Content come from api to pdf in C#?

Tags: c#, api

How can I convert response content from an API call to PDF in C#?

I convert the response content, but when I open the `.pdf` it is encoded and I can't read anything in the PDF; I am using iTextSharp.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.preprod.invoicing.eta.gov.eg/api/v1/documents/J0SHWN9K3HBHT2G65WRCX5WE10/pdf");
client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer [TOKEN]");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "75fd0698a2e84d6b8a3cb94ae54530f3=a01a7047204e21c04caf18b0706f845d");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
           
{
    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

    try
    {
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\M.Faysal\Desktop\id\E-Invoice\SDK\PreProduction\Mddddd.pdf", FileMode.Create));
                         
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(response.Content));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally 
    { 
        doc.Close(); 
    }
}
```